# Writing a Rails Integration test for a search controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am testing my app. I have a feature where you can search for registered members by first name, last name, city, state, etc... I think an integration test would work better than a controller test, but I am having a hard time figuring out where to start. Here is the code from my controller:

```
class MsearchesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @msearch = Msearch.new
    @first_name = User.uniq.pluck(:first_name)
    @last_name = User.uniq.pluck(:last_name)
    @state = User.uniq.pluck(:state)
    @cities = User.uniq.pluck(:city)
  end

  def create
    @msearch = Msearch.create(msearch_params)
    redirect_to @msearch
  end

  def show
    @users = User.all

    @msearch = Msearch.find(params[:id])
    @first_name = User.uniq.pluck(:first_name)
    @last_name = User.uniq.pluck(:last_name)
    @states = User.uniq.pluck(:state)
    @cities = User.uniq.pluck(:city)
  end

  def update
    @msearch = Msearch.new
  end

private 

  def msearch_params
     params.require(:msearch).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :state, :city, :agency)
  end

end
```

Any help in getting me started would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree this is better tested at the acceptance level than the Controller level since there's nothing you could really assert on in a controller test that would verify it's doing what it's supposed to. The Controller delegates work to business objects and views. You need to exercise all of them to verify that it's doing the job correctly. Controller unit tests are usually redundant for this reason.

I would use something like the following to test this functionality at the acceptance level (assumes you are using Capybara and FactoryGirl).

```
feature "User Search", type: :feature do

  scenario "search for user by first name" do
    @frodo = create(:user, first_name: "Frodo")
    @sam = create(:user, first_name: "Sam")

    visit new_msearch_path
    fill_in "user_first_name", with: "Frodo"
    click_button "Search"

    expect(page).to have_content "Frodo"
    expect(page).to_not have_content "Sam" 
  end

  # ... similar tests to cover each field / search case ...

end
```

Is the `Msearch` class from a gem? or did you implement it yourself? If it's your own class, you might also want to be test it at the unit level so you can exercise more complex edge cases without the overhead of the full stack.